# Redericting stdout and stdin

Tags: c, stdout, filestream, stdin

I would like to redericting stdout, stderr to file and stdin from char*. My goal is make it in C.

When i run this code:

```
int main(){
        stdout=fopen("/home/user/file.txt","w");
    printf("aaaa");
    printf("\nbbbb");
    system("/bin/bash");
    sprintf("stdin","exit");
    return 0;
}
```

File didn't have for some string and bash take argument from console. Where is bug??

Comment: I have some troubles understanding your question, but it seems to me that you want to redirect the output of `bash` to a file... correct?

Comment: You can close file descriptors (even stdin, etc) using `close()`, and open them with different handles...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to assign to `stdout`. Instead, you (probably) want to use [`freopen`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/freopen/), in your case like: `freopen("/home/user/file.txt","w", stdout);`

If/when you're doing all the processing internally, you're generally better off writing the code to receive a `FILE *` as a parameter, and passing the correct value. That doesn't work when you have external code that writes directly to `stdout` though.

Edit: I should probably also mention one other serious problem with `freopen` -- no method is provided to restore it to the previous stream. It's up t you to use `freopen` again, and know the path that will write to the console (or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

`stdout` should not be used as an lvalue.  Try the fprintf() function instead of printf() to get the desired effect.

As for redirecting the stdout from bash, can you not just call it with `/usr/bin/bash >> /home/user/file.txt`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <io.h>

int main(void){
    int ret;
    FILE *fp;
    int  stdout_bk;

    stdout_bk = dup(fileno(stdout));
    fp=fopen("/home/user/file.txt","w");
    dup2(fileno(fp), fileno(stdout));
    ret = system("/bin/bash");
    //flushall();//for vc
    fflush(stdout);//for gcc 
    fclose(fp);

    dup2(stdout_bk, fileno(stdout));//restore

    return 0;
}
```